# Stirling formula approximation for Combinatorial

Tags: solution-verification, induction, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

For this [question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cK8H.png), could I ask for some help regarding getting the eventual value of that combinatorial that involve an extra term.
As normally
$$\ C(n, n/2) = \frac{(2^n)}{\sqrt {\frac{n \pi}{2}}} $$

So how can I proceed to do this? As I am unsure on how to use $\ (1 + \frac{x}{k})^k  -> e^x $ in solving this question.

Answer (score 0):

Write out the binomial coefficient $C(\cdot, \cdot)$ in terms of factorials and apply Stirling's approximation.
\begin{align}
\binom{n}{n/2 + \sqrt{n}}
&= \frac{n!}{(n/2 - \sqrt{n})!(n/2+\sqrt{n})!}
\\
&\sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \frac{n^{n+1/2}}{
(n/2-  \sqrt{n})^{\frac{n}{2} - \sqrt{n} + \frac{1}{2}}
(n/2+  \sqrt{n})^{\frac{n}{2} +\sqrt{n} + \frac{1}{2}}
}
\\
&= \frac{2^{n+1}}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}\frac{1}{
(1 - \frac{2}{\sqrt{n}})^{\frac{n}{2} - \sqrt{n} + \frac{1}{2}}
(1 + \frac{2}{\sqrt{n}})^{\frac{n}{2} + \sqrt{n} + \frac{1}{2}}
}
\end{align}

When you multiply by $\sqrt{n}/2^n$, the factor in front becomes $\sqrt{2/\pi}$, and it remains to take the limit of the complicated second term.

The denominator can be rewritten as
$$[(1-2/\sqrt{n})(1+2/\sqrt{n})]^{\frac{n}{2} - \sqrt{n} + \frac{1}{2}} 
\cdot 
(1+2/\sqrt{n})^{2\sqrt{n}}$$

Note that the first term is
$(1-4/n)^{\frac{n}{2} - \sqrt{n} + \frac{1}{2}}$.
By a hand-wavy argument, $(1-4/n)^n \approx e^{-4}$ for large $n$, so the above term approaches $e^{-2}$. (This can be made more rigorous.)

For the second term, $(1+2/\sqrt{n})^{\sqrt{n}} \to e^2$, so $(1+2/\sqrt{n})^{2\sqrt{n}} \to e^4$.

Comment: Hi Can I ask regarding the second and third step, how did you arrive with that two equation after applying Stirling's approximation?